MySQL: Truncate Partition Followed By Drop Partition
I have a range partitioned table, partitioned by day, where I want to drop data older than 30 days periodically.
My understanding is that ALTER TABLE .. DROP PARTITION will lock the whole table blocking DML in other partitions, whereas ALTER TABLE .. TRUNCATE PARTITION will not lock the table allowing DML in other partitions.
If I want to minimize the impact of pruning data, does it make sense to first truncate a partition before dropping it? If the partition is empty will the DROP PARTITION command hold the lock for less time or does the MySQL server optimise it so that even if the partition holds data the meta data lock is only acquired after dropping the rows?

Dropping a partition and truncating a partition are both quick actions, regardless of the size of the partition. There's no advantage to truncating first.
However, both ALTER TABLE statements need to acquire an exclusive metadata lock on the table.
Any outstanding transaction that has referenced the table, even in a read-only query, holds its own metadata lock, which blocks the ALTER TABLE.
The best practice is to finish transactions promptly. Then your ALTER TABLE will proceed.

Thanks, Bill. I must have been looking at old documentation which states that truncate will prune locks https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-locking.html#:~:text=TRUNCATE%20PARTITION%20prunes%20locks%3B%20only,locks%20on%20the%20table%20level.

Look at the next sentence in that documentation.

Gotcha, I missed the “additionally” part and assumed the 2 statements were mutually exclusive.
